# Negative diagonal values in hessian matrix in optim function

Tags: r, optimization, mle, standard-error, hessian

I am trying to estimate the parameters of my log-likelihood function using `optim` in `R`. The optimisation process converges and the parameter estimates are quite intuitive and according to the expectations. The problem arises when I want to compute the standard errors for the estimated coefficients using `sqrt(diag(solve(- optim$hessian)))` that results in `NaN`s for many coefficients which is due to having negative values on the diagonal of the hessian matrix. This issue, I assume, is quite prevalent as it has been asked on some other SO posts like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52538573/how-to-adjust-an-odd-behaving-hessian-to-calculate-standard-errors-with-optim) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59951587/why-do-i-get-negative-variance-from-hessian-matrix-in-optim-function).

What struck me by surprise was that, despite the frequency of the problem, almost no concrete explanation or solution has been proposed in order to deal with such situations. So, I would greatly appreciate if someone could clarify why the hessian matrix is not positive definite (I am minimising the negative log-likelihood) especially considering that the optimisation has converged. Also, how I can proceed and compute the standard errors? Trying different initial values does not seem to be a robust solution and has been proved ineffective previously. In some cases, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52538573/how-to-adjust-an-odd-behaving-hessian-to-calculate-standard-errors-with-optim) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111352/negative-variance-from-inverse-hessian-matrix), using the `hessian` function from `numDeriv` package is recommended in order to numerically compute the hessian matrix at the optimal values. In my case this results in the following error which I cannot resolve:

```
  Error in Daprox[, k] <- (f1 - f2)/(2 * h[i]) :
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
```

Almost similar error is produced when the `hessian` function from `pracma` package is used. I am not posting the log-likelihood function as it is rather long and written in an ad-hoc, but correct, way. So, I assume it would not be helpful in answering my question.

Comment: It doesn't need the exact hessian so it just computes an approximation which it can do faster.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, thanks for your comment but could you please explain a bit further? How do you suggest to proceed in such case?

Comment: numDeriv and pracma packages have hessian functions.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, Yes, I have tried both, but as I explained they produce the error regarding the matrix subscripts.

Comment: Problems with the hessian can also occur when you don't have enough data for the number of parameters.  Also it is possible that there is an error in your code.